# jQuery : remove element except inside element

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

Is there any way to remove element except inside element:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="images/rep.png" title="rep">
    <img src="http://example.com/uploads/rep.png" class="thumbnail" alt="rep" title="rep">
  </a>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="http://example.com/uploads/rep.png" class="thumbnail" alt="rep" title="rep">
</div>
```

I wrote this code but not work:

```
$(".gallery").contents().filter(".thumbnail").remove();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery has an `unwrap()` method which removes the parent node and leaves the matched element in place:

```
$(".gallery").contents().filter(".thumbnail").unwrap();

// or (faster)
$(".gallery .thumbnail").unwrap();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: Or `$(".gallery .thumbnail").unwrap();`

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".thumbnail").unwrap()
```

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Answer (score 0):

Might be a simpler method, but:

```
$('.gallery').each( function() {

    var img = $(this).find('img');
    $(this).children("a").remove();

    $(this).append(img);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
innerhtml = $("div.gallery .thumbnail").get();
$("div.gallery").html(innerhtml);
```